# How do you get a django model instance from an Angular select dropdown field containing a django-rest-api field with a foreignkey?

Tags: javascript, python, django, angular, django-rest-framework

I have an application that runs `Angular` on the client side and `Django` on the backend, im using `Django-request-framework` for my model serialization, whereby my model has a model named `Job` which in turn has a field named `job_category` which points to a model `JobCategory` in a foreignkey relationship like this

**models.py**

`JobCategory(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_value=100)`

`Job(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_value=200)
    job_category = models.ForeignKeyField(JobCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

So on my angular component i have a select field which loops over the job categories like this

**Angular component html form**

```
<select id="category" class="form-control color-gray" ngModel name='category'>
         <option *ngFor='let category of job_categories' [ngValue]="category.id" >{{ category.title }}
         </option>
</select>
```

everything works fine at that point until i select a job category from the Angular options and post it, then i get the error that

`"ValueError at /api/jobs/↵Cannot assign "'Companion Care'": "Job.job_category" must be a "JobCategory" instance.`

how can i fix this or how do you select an instance of `JobCategory`?

**EDIT**

Here are my serializers

**serializers.py**

```
class JobCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = JobCategory
        fields = ['id','title']

 class JobsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.CharField(source='job_category')

    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields =['id','title','category']
```

Comment: Your error is in the serializer. Can you post it?

Comment: @Melvyn Sure, I've edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah yes, that's a common mistake. You rely on the string method here to pass the foreign key as a human readable name. However, your drop-down correctly passes the ID. I suppose you use this serializer also for the RetrieveApiView, so you have a simple way of inlining the category in the detail view.

To fix, just this update problem, use a second serializer for updating:

```
class JobUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source='job_category')

    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields =['id','title','category']
```

If you want to keep one serializer, then you need more work fixing the frontend, as your payload will become nested, but you keep access to both id and name (updating by primary key is a lot safer and cleaner as it isn't subject to i18n, for example):

```py
class JobSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = JobCategorySerializer(source='job_category')

    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields =['id','title','category']
```

Output will be:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "dog",
    "category": {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "animal"
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using Viewsets to handle my views and i forgot to mention this happens when i am doing a POST request not the PUT/PATCH requests(though i haven't tried that yet) in that case is the second method easier?

Comment: It's a frontend choice really. If you only provide ID's, then you need to cache the id to title somewhere. However, if you already keep all categories in your frontend as a mapping, then you only need an id to render a job, since you can fetch the category ID from there. I've seen and used both. I'm partial to the first, but only slightly, cause in practice you have the mappings or an extra request for a title is cheap.

Comment: Now getting a new error with the second method, `Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got int.`

Comment: Yes, you need to change the output to match the structure I presented, so a nested object for category. I have too little knowledge of Angular to help you there, sorry.

Comment: Do i need a new view for the first method or somehow change from viewset to an APIView?

Comment: You should be able to implement `create` and switch serializer_class there.